# how to find whether given model is overfitting or underfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting

i have trained the neural network model and obtain result shown in fig, can somebody explain me from given image, whether model is over-fitting, under-fitting or best fit.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: no, it does not look like your model is overfitting, **assuming you are treating your validation data as your test data and you are not tuning a hyperparameter.**

In general, we say that a model overfits training data when the training error is lower than test error.  In order to optimize model hyperparameters, though, we typically split our training data into another training and validation dataset. So, if you are also using this validation set to pick a hyperparemter, e.g. the structure of your inner layer, then you really can't say whether or not your  model is overfitting (you'll need a separate data set to test out your model).